# Recommendation of actuator

Tags: stepper-motor, imageprocessing, actuator

I had posted about my project earlier in this forum:

[PID algorithm implementation using computer vision](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16138/4844)

Now I am currently stuck in a stage whether I am concerned whether I chose the wrong actuator.

The stepper motor controller needs input in terms of number of steps and time duration of rotation. I find it very difficult to estimate a base scale to do the calculations as my angle of tilt varies according to both the parameters. I had been discussing this with someone and he suggested that I use a servo motor because I was planning to use the OpenCV Kalman filter algorithm. According to him, if I plug in my motor commands into my input vector matrix, I can actually get a value between 0 and 255 that could be used to operate my servos. I am looking forward to hear your thoughts whether I should switch to a servo or try using a stepper.

My main concern is that my maze's ball keeps spinning back and forth even for a small tilt in the maze and I am not following a standard approach in determining the tilt required for my maze to go to a point

Answer (score -2):

Unpredictable exciter from input to output must be as frustrating as its self-excited slip or step advance. Suggest you use a reliable servo controller or get rid of the stray noise triggered step.

Try to characterize

- the position error under different conditions, noise and level
- velocity error from circuit, noise & level
- acceleration error, noise and level.

Did you consider effects of noise from 1.8deg steps ?